# Does mahabharata mention conflict between shungas and indo greeks?

Tags: mahabharata, kings

> Several works, such as the Mahabharata and the Yuga Purana describe
>   the conflict between the Shungas and the Indo-Greeks.

From here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunga_Empire

Where does mahabharata mention shungas and indo greeks?

Comment: The period of Mahabharata is about 3000 BCE, at that time even Greek was not into existence forget about Indo-Greeks. There must be some mistake in the references, please check it.

Comment: @B.N.Bhaskar this must be one of the misinterpretations of indologists, where they want to prove yavan as greeks from 300 bce but yavans in epics are mentioned as a border state to india not greeks.